# Replace data in a column for a character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table having data like as below:

```
  Description   Name
    ABC           AB
    ABCD          AB, BC, CD
    ABCDF         AB, BC
```

Now i needed output as below:

```
  Description   Name
    ABC           AB
    ABCD          AB, BC and CD
    ABCDF         AB and BC
```

How can i get desired output in SQL? please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    Description, 
    ISNULL(
       REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Name), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(Name), 0),1,'dna ')), 
    Name) Name
From YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a8d3/3)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as

```
declare @str nvarchar(200)
set @str = 'Ali, ahmed, riaz, zoya'
select SUBSTRING(@str, 0, (len(@str) - charindex(',', reverse(@str)))) +
Replace(SUBSTRING(@str, (len(@str) - charindex(',', reverse(@str))), len(@str)), 
', ', ' and ')
```